# Nested Objects in Realm React-Native

Tags: react-native, realm

**Question**

How does Realm React Native perform with two way linking in parent-child nested relationships?

**Example**

I have an Invoice object, which is made up of InvoiceLines. In the old database, each row in the InvoiceLine table had a reference to its parent Invoice's ID. So a simple 'WHERE ID= " query to get from either an InvoiceLine to its Invoice or an Invoice to all of its InvoiceLines.

In Realm, I'm going to have the following schema (paraphrased):

```
class Invoice {};
Invoice.schema = {
  name: 'Invoice',
  properties: {
    ...
    lines: {type: 'list', objectType: 'InvoiceLine'}
  }
}

class InvoiceLine {};
InvoiceLine.schema = {
  name: 'InvoiceLine',
  properties: {
    ...
    invoice: 'Invoice',
  }
}
```

How does the performance of this direct linking compare with using ID's and doing it the traditional way within Realm? Is there a memory tradeoff to store all of those links?

Comment: Interesting that you're storing the `invoice` property as an `Invoice` object. I've been using `invoiceId` to keep track of parent objects. When you create an `InvoiceLine` record, do you use `{ ..., invoice: realmInvoice, ... }`? And when calling `myInvoiceLine.invoice`, does it get the up-to-date `Invoice` record from the Realm DB?

Comment: FYI, here's the link in Realm JS' Github Issues to track this feature: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/343

Comment: "When you create an InvoiceLine record, do you use { ..., invoice: realmInvoice, ... }?" - That's right.
"And when calling myInvoiceLine.invoice, does it get the up-to-date Invoice record from the Realm DB?" - Haven't got to a bit that uses the parent yet, but hoping so! Have you had issues?

Comment: Perfect. No issues yet just getting a feel for it before updating my code from using IDs to using object links. It's not very well documented so you gotta make a lot of assumptions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using links should perform almost identically or better than using ID's in most cases. Following links will be much faster than looking up by ID. The only performance hit you will have is when deleting objects. When deleting instances of the parent class all child links pointing to the deleted parent are set to `null`. This is something that you probably want done anyway. When deleting child objects sometimes there is some internal bookkeeping that needs to be updated, but this is generally fast enough to be imperceptible.