# Deleting children on deleting parent on Realm

Tags: react-native, realm

I understand that the realm  works similar to mongodb. My question is, what if I want to delete the children and their children (basically the whole branch of data starting from the node I am deleting)?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143953/nested-objects-in-realm-react-native) gave me some insights on how relationships work in realm. But I am still confused.

Answer (score 2):

Cascading deletes are not yet supported in Realm. Until this feature is supported you need to delete child objects manually. Something like the following might work:

```
function deleteObjectGraph(object, type, realm) {
    let objectSchema = realm.schema.find((objectSchema) => objectSchema.name == type);

    // delete all child objects
    for (let propName in objectSchema.properties) {
         let prop = objectSchema.properties[propName];

         // for list properties delete all elements and their children
         if (prop.type == 'list') {
             object[propName].forEach((listObject) =>
                 deleteObjectGraph(listObject, prop.objectType, realm);
             );
         }

         // for object properties delete object and all children
         if (prop.type == 'object' && object[propName] != null) {
             deleteObjectGraph(object[propName], prop.objectType, realm);
         }
    }

    // delete the object
    realm.delete(object);
}
```

I have not tested this and this will not work for circular object graphs or may have issues in cases where objects are reused.